# Why doesn't this keyword function lookup work in a hashmap?

Tags: clojure

I guess I need some eyeballs on this to make some sense of this

```
    (println record)
    (println (keys record) " - " (class record) " : " (:TradeId record) (:Stock record))
    (doall  (map #(println "Key " % "Value " (% record)) (keys record)))
```

Output:

```
{:Stock ATT, :AccountId 1, :TradeId 37, :Qty 100, :Price 117, :Date 2011-02-24T18:30:00.000Z, :Notes SPLIT 1:10, :Type B, :Brokerage 81.12}

(:Stock :AccountId :TradeId :Qty :Price :Date :Notes :Type :Brokerage)  -  clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap  :  nil ATT

Key  :Stock Value  ATT
Key  :AccountId Value  1
Key  :TradeId Value  37
...
```

The issue is `(:TradeId record)` doesn't work even though it exists as a key. Iterating through all keys and values - Line 3 - yields the right value.
Tried renaming the column in the csv but no change in behavior. I see no difference from the other columns (which work) except that this is the first column in the csv.

The hashmap is created from code like this - reading records from a CSV. Standard code from the clojure.data.csv package.

```
(->> (csv/read-csv reader)
           csv-data->maps
           (map #(my-function some-args %))
           doall))


(defn csv-data->maps 
  "Return the csv records as a vector of maps"
  [csv-data]
  (map zipmap
       (->> (first csv-data) ;; First row is the header
            (map keyword) ;; Drop if you want string keys instead
            repeat)
       (rest csv-data)))
```

Comment: I would try printing out the hex of the names of the keywords. Maybe there's something strange like a leading BOM hiding in the problem key. The "first column" thing is definitely suspicous. And/or maybe you'll see something if you do a hex dump of the first few lines of the input file.

Comment: @jas - if you would like to post this as an answer, I'd give you the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure, I'd be glad to. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "first column" thing is definitely suspicous and points to some invisible characters such as a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) quietly attaching itself to your first keyword.

To debug try printing out the hex of the names of the keywords. And/or maybe you'll see something if you do a hex dump, e.g., with `head -n 2 file.csv | od -x`, of the first few lines of the input file.

Answer (score 1):

I would try two things. First, print the type of each key. They should all be clojure.lang.Keyword, if the creation code you included is accurate and `my-function` preserves their type; but if you created it in some other way and misremembered, you might discover that the key is a symbol, or a string or something like that. In general, don't use `println` on anything but strings, because it's pretty low-fidelity. `prn` is better at conveying an accurate picture of your data - it's not perfect, but at least you can tell a string from a keyword with it.

Second, look at the printed values more carefully, e.g. with `od -t x1` - or you could do it in process with something like:

```
(let [k (key (first m)), s (name k)]
  (clojure.string/join " " 
                       (for [c s] 
                         (format "%02x" (int c)))))
```

If the result isn't `"53 74 6f 63 6b"`, then you have some weird characters in your file - maybe nonprinting characters, maybe something that looks like a capital S but isn't, whatever.

Comment: Tried that - all of the keys were Keyword. I was searching for some function that would highlight unprintable characters. Tried prn too - same output as println. All clean

Answer (score 1):

Once I reached the point of trying anything, I copied the keyword from the REPL and pasted it into VSCode and sure enough - there was this weird looking character `:?Id` within the keyword. Using the weird keyword, the lookup worked.

Workaround: Added a dummy column as the first column.

Then things started to click into place, I remembered reading something on BOM in the csv reader project docs. https://github.com/clojure/data.csv#byte-order-mark

Downloaded a hexdump file viewer which confirmed the problem bytes at the start of the file.

o;?Id,AccountId,...

Final solution: Before passing the reader to the data.csv read function, skip over the unwanted bytes.

`(.skip reader 1)`

The world makes sense again.

Comment: Whenever you see a `?` in java land, there most likely is something borked about the character encoding